# Android root device run application after system boot from script

Tags: android, linux, bootcompleted, android-rom

I am creating small initialization application. Let's call it `InitApp`. That application is responsible for initialization Wifi connection and update/download another application from server. The `InitApp` should run automatically every time after system boot successfully and it should go throw all steps (init wifi etc).

Initialization wifi connection and update another application from server works properly. **Problem is with starting application on boot completed.** (I don't want to use `BroadcastReceiver`, because it requires that application must be run at least once.). I have rooted device and `InitApp` will be pre-installed. So If I got rooted device with clean custom ROM where `InitApp` has already installed as system app it should start automatically after boot completed. This is my goal.

As a super user I get access to system files. I am thinking about changing system configuration and add the command `am start -n  com.my.package/.MainActivity`. But I don't how. Which file can I modify and add this command?